# sql with left join subquery

Tags: mysql, join

so i want to ask if it is possible to join this two queries. 
I got three tables: 
**apiary** (can have multiple hives) 
**hive** (should only be on one apiary at the time) 
**movedate** (the m:n table between apiary and hive, with date field when the hive is on the apiary)

My first one is this, it just get's the users Apiaries:

```
SELECT apiary_id as id, name
            FROM
            apiary 
            WHERE
            modus = '1' //if apiary is aktive
            AND
            user_id = ?
```

the second one then counts how many hives are on each apiary at the moment:

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM 
            movedate 
                LEFT JOIN //get rows with the same apiary_id
                apiary
                ON
                movedate.apiary_id = apiary.apiary_id
                LEFT JOIN //get rows with the same hive_id
                hive
                ON
                movedate.hive_id = hive.hive_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  //outer join to check for the joungest date
                movedate as movedate2
                ON movedate.hive_id = movedate2.hive_id
                    AND (movedate.date < movedate2.date
                    OR (movedate.date = movedate2.date AND movedate.id < movedate2.id))
            WHERE 
            hive.modus = '1'  //check if hive is active
            AND
            apiary.apiary_id = $ap_id  //get apiary id (at the moment to this query for each apiary)
            AND
            movedate2.hive_id IS NULL  (dont get the old entries)
```

I tried simply to move the whole second SQL Query into the first one as sub query in SELECT but it seems that it's not possible to do a left join in SELECT sub query? I use PDO if there is a special command to use?

I would be happy about any tips!

Cheers
Hannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a `group by`:

```
SELECT apiary.apiary_id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM movedate LEFT JOIN //get rows with the same apiary_id
     apiary
     ON movedate.apiary_id = apiary.apiary_id LEFT JOIN //get rows with the same hive_id
     hive
     ON movedate.hive_id = hive.hive_id LEFT OUTER JOIN  //outer join to check for the joungest date
     movedate as movedate2
     ON movedate.hive_id = movedate2.hive_id AND
        (movedate.date < movedate2.date OR
         (movedate.date = movedate2.date AND movedate.id < movedate2.id)
        )
WHERE hive.modus = '1' AND //check if hive is active
      movedate2.hive_id IS NULL  (dont get the old entries)
GROUP BY apiary.apiary_id;
```

Comment: Awesome, my way of thinking was way to complicated! :) Thank you very much!